# how to get .jar file from .jnlp file?

Tags: java, jar, jnlp

To play the go game, I went to http://www.gokgs.com/download.jsp to start the client with Java Web Start. Essentially, it is a .jnlp file that can automatically update the client.

It is cool. Still, I am wondering how I can fetch the underlying .jar file from this .jnlp file. I checked my local java 6.0 cache directory, and didn't find any .jar file over there.

Anybody knows how to get a stand-alone version of this cgoban client?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JNLP is just an XML file.  You can just open the .jnlp file and it will tell you where the .jar file is located.  http://files.gokgs.com/javaBin/cgoban.jar

```
<jnlp codebase="http://files.gokgs.com" href="javaBin/cgoban.jnlp">
    ...
    <jar href="javaBin/cgoban.jar" main="true"/>
```

The relevant attributes are the `jnlp[codebase]` and the `jar[href]`.

Comment: Actually,  I am using the alternative URL: http://files.gokgs.com/javaBin/cgoban-nfa.jnlp, because I don't want to associate SGF files to this program (having another exclusive SGF viewer/editor). When I open this cgoban-nfa.jnlp, I couldn't find the similar line.

Comment: Found it. It is at the 6-th line from the tail. I was looking for the file from the head of the file. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

If you open jnlp file in text editor there is a link to jar file. In your case it is:
http://files.gokgs.com/javaBin/cgoban.jar

Comment: Thanks, it is great to get this stand-alone client to play on KGS, :P